# Custom hook with useContext not updating when calling updater function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, use-state, use-context

I created a custom react hook using useContext & useState but when calling useState function inside the consumer the state isn't updating:

```js
import { createContext, ReactNode, useContext, useState, Dispatch, SetStateAction } from "react"

interface Pub {
    [key: string]: any
}

const PubCtx = createContext<{ pub: null | Pub, setPub: Dispatch<SetStateAction<Pub | null>> }>({ pub: null, setPub: () => { } });

export const usePub = () => useContext(PubCtx);


export default function PubProvider({ children }: { children : ReactNode }){
    const [pub, setPub] = useState<null | Pub>(null);
    return (
        <PubCtx.Provider value={{ pub, setPub }}>{ children }</PubCtx.Provider>
    );
}
```

I wrapped the my layout with `PubProvider` and when I used `usePub` to call `setPub()` the function doesn't get called and the state doesn't change.

Comment: Can you show us how you're updating the state in the component wrapped by `PubProvider`?

Answer (score 0):

I put your code into codesandbox and... it works, surprisingly :) (not really)

https://codesandbox.io/s/solitary-lake-4c4zpr?file=/src/App.tsx

I can imagine 2 possible problems:

1. You use context consumer outside the provider;
2. Improper dependencies for some other hooks that uses consumed value.